# Add input to simple_form in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a rails 3 application where a user has_many addresses. I'm trying to make a form in which a user can add fields to create new addresses by clicking on a plus icon. The issue is that I can't add fields with correct name into my simple_form with javascript.

The fields are well added to my view, but they all have the same name :  `user[addresses_attributes][0][name]` instead of `user[addresses_attributes][0 to x number][name]`. Because of that, I can't save new addresses... Can someone help me ?

my edit_addresses.html.erb :

```
<%= simple_form_for(current_user) do |f| %>
  <% current_user.addresses.each do |address| %>
    <div class="address_preview">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses, address do |a| %>
        <%= a.input :name %>
        <%= a.input :description %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<a href='<%= new_address_path(current_user) %>' data-remote='true'>Add</i></a>
```

When a user click on "Add" he is redirect_to my new.js.html file:

```
$('#addresses_container').append('<%= j render partial: 'new_address', locals: { target: @address } %>');
```

And the 'new_address' partial is:

```
<div class="address_preview">
  <%= simple_form_for(current_user) do |f| %>
    <% f.simple_fields_for :addresses, target do |t| %>
      <%= t.input :name %>
      <%= t.input :description %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is very long, but is in [Railscasts #197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2).